# Not a File Exception when running pyspark in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, exception, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I scoop two datasets from 2 diff sources into Hive. I created a union of the two tables in hive using

```
create table db.table as select table 1 union select table 2
```

I used this table in pyspark by HiveContext to perform some analytical functions like string indexing on of the columns.

```
hc=HiveContext(sc)
data = hc.sql("select * from db.table")
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row, HiveContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="col_cat", outputCol="cat_indexed")
indexed=indexer.fit(data).transform(data)
```

However I get the following error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.fit.
: java.io.IOException: Not a file:
```

So I went into HDFS

```
hadoop fs -ls /hive/db/table
```

and I found the table, I dont know whats the issue here.
I feel its because I did not create an external table. but it worked last time without external.

Comment: Does `data.first()` give you anything?

Comment: No it gives me the same error

Comment: Have you tried to [load the table](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) in spark?

Comment: Also, have you configured spark to use `hive-site.xml`?

Comment: I havent tried loading the table from spark, I directly created a union in hive and accessed it through HiveContext in spark, but now I think the table is not loading at all as data.show() is also giving an error.

Comment: Ok so here is what I found, I did `hadoop fs - ls /hive/db/table` and I got 2 directories in which the file is located, but when I load the table as a dataframe, it tries looking at the directories and gives `Not a File error`. Now I need it to access it like this `/hive/db/table/file`  I dont know how to let spark know that.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found a fix, I moved the files from the directories
i.e from

```
/hive/db/table/file
```

to

```
/hive/db/file
```

by doing

```
Hadoop fs -mv /hive/db/table/file /hive/db/file
```

and now it works, the problem was that union in Hive created a partition between the tables and hence created additional directories to save the files. so when Spark tried to access them it pointed to the directories. So I changed the file location to where spark was pointing.